# How to use Oauth in order to log‑in on .googleapis.com on almost any arbitrary endpoints domains from the web browser?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

Simple question : how do I set a cookie or get bearer token for the googleapis.com domain name ?

I’m meaning there’re many tutorials in how to log‑in the current user being logged‑in on Google, but they all work using a local app.

In my case, I need to send data to the googleapis.com domain name using Oauth for my current user but **through his web browser**. [I know this is possible because although deprecated, that stuff still works for doing it](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/dns/v1/dns.responsePolicies.create) and even might seem to be able to read the answer using javascript from cross‑origin without preflight. I see it works but I don’t understand how.

Comment: It seems to be achieved through Google app engine, but I don’t need to use app engine if it’s not needed.